# Haskell run-length encoding function

Tags: list, haskell, encoding, integer, tuples

This encoding function expects the following output, 
`code "aaccbbaa" = [('a',2),('c',2),('b',2),('a',2)`

However, this is my output.
`code "aaccbbaa" = [('a',4),('c',2),('b',2)]`

Here is my function,

```
code :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a,Int)]
code [] = []
code (x:xs) = [(x, length(filter(==x)(x:xs)))] ++ code(filter (/=x)(xs))
```

How do I make it recount that when the next alpha letter appears?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [group](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html) function in `Data.List`

```
code :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a,Int)]
code = map (\x -> (head x, length x)) . group
```

---

```
λ> code "aaccbbaa"
[('a',2),('c',2),('b',2),('a',2)]
```

Comment: This is very concise coding. 
I just checked about group function, `group "aaccbbaa" ` outputs `["aa","cc","bb","aa"]`

Answer (score 1):

A `foldr` with a helper function should be sufficient to handle this job as follows;

```
code :: Char -> [(Char,Int)] -> [(Char,Int)]
code c [(_,0)]    = [(c,1)]
code c ((x,n):ts) | c == x    = (x,n+1):ts
                  | otherwise = (c,1):(x,n):ts

rle :: String -> [(Char,Int)]
rle = foldr code [(' ',0)]
```

Well as per your comment to accept any type with instances of `Eq` Class we may simplify the `rle` function. On the other hand the accepted answer involves 3 time taking operations like `group`, `map` and `length`. For a single use it won't matter, however if you will be using this function millions of times on some words or sentences then i would advise the following which only runs once through the list.

```
rle :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a,Int)]
rle = foldr code []
      where code c []         = [(c,1)]
            code c ((x,n):ts) | c == x    = (x,n+1):ts
                              | otherwise = (c,1):(x,n):ts
```

Comment: This works as well, and easier to under. 
But it changes the original data construction `code :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a,Int)]`.

Comment: @BCKN You are right... I have corrected the code according to your needs. It does the job only with a single pass over the list in O(n) time.